# Extract only rows that are not in both sheets into a third sheet

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

I have 2 excel sheets with similar column values (legal_id). Is there a way to extract only rows that are not in both sheets into a third sheet? For example if social security number 111111 isn't in both sheets, then that persons row would be placed in the third sheet..please see images below.

- Sheet 1

[image: Sheet 1]

- Sheet 2

[image: Sheet 2]

- Sheet3_DesiredResults

[image: Sheet 3 Desired Results]

Before I get backlash about not attempting code this is what I tried,

I thought this formula would highlight true or false to values that are not in the same sheet, then I could just delete every field that returned true to be in both sheets , but it doesn't work. I'm not a programmer, I need help. Please don't tell me to take a VBA tutorial.Instead of making a third sheet , I made a helper column on the first sheet and used the formula:

```
=(ISNA(MATCH(A2,Sheet1!A:A,0)))=FALSE
```

Comment: Are "legal id" unique for each person? Do you need a formula based solution only? The final result can be split in 2 ranges?

Comment: this question looks very familiar, although the user changed. It's still true what I wrote in my last comment back then: If you use the formula in sheet1, you are checking a value of sheet1 for all values in sheet1 this will always be true.

Comment: I dont know what you mean by spit in 2 ranges but yes the legal_ids are all unique they are really SSNs. I will take any solution. I just need all the legal_ids they are not in both sheets, into a seperate sheet or a formula that can state true or false as to whether they are in both sheets and i can delete them based off that.

Comment: Ok FunThomas thanks for your input, I am a baby charizard I have no idea what youre talking about.  Evil Blue Monkey can my code provided be modified to do this?

Comment: Probably a COUNT.IF() could make the job. If IDs are unique, you just create a column in the third sheet where you count any ID of the first sheet that is also in the second sheet; then you use a second column to check if the second sheet shares any ID with the first sheet. I'm wrinting something to see if it's viable.

Comment: I cannot prove who you are, but even the screenshots are the same.

Comment: It doesnt matter, the code doesnt even run anyways. Thanks for the help anyways guys.

Answer (score 0):

Like anticipated in my comment, you might use 2 ranges in the third sheet and the COUNT.IF function. The formulas you need are these:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Sheet2!$A:$A,Sheet1!$A2)=0,Sheet1!A2,0)
```

.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Sheet1!$A:$A,Sheet2!$A2)=0,Sheet2!A2,0)
```

Place them in 2 proper cell in the third sheet (let's say A2 and E2), drag them to cover the two lists. Empty cells or cells with IDs in both Sheet1 and Sheet2 will return 0. If you don't like 0 and you prefear "", you might use these:

```
    =IF(IF(COUNTIF(Sheet2!$A:$A,Sheet1!$A2)=0,Sheet1!A2,0)=0,"",IF(COUNTIF(Sheet2!$A:$A,Sheet1!$A2)=0,Sheet1!A2,0))
```

.

```
    =IF(IF(COUNTIF(Sheet1!$A:$A,Sheet2!$A2)=0,Sheet2!A2,0)=0,"",IF(COUNTIF(Sheet1!$A:$A,Sheet2!$A2)=0,Sheet2!A2,0))
```

Comment: I try to type this formula in the formula field and get this error: "Theres a problem with this formula. Not trying to type a formula? When the the first character is an equal(=) or minus(-) sign, excel think's its a forumla"... Well duh excel. I dont know whats wrong now smh. Im about to give up.

Comment: They are 2 different formulas. One for each range. Also, i've mistakenly left a few extra points. I've removed them. Does it work now?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved your query. Please have a look below.

First as expected, i created 2 sheets with same data as mentioned in image for simplicity.

[Sheet 1 with Helper column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QhfO.png)

[Sheet 2 with Helper column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpRxw.png)

Step 2 : I converted the sheet data into table for efficiency.

Step 3 : I used the COUNTIF function and IF function in Sheet 1 Helper column throughout.

```
=IF( COUNTIFS(Sheet2!Legal_id, [@[Legal_id]]) = 0, "N/A","" )
```

Similiarly we have to implement this formula in Sheet 2 Helper column.

```
=IF( COUNTIFS( Book1!Legal_id, [@[Legal_id]]) = 0, "N/A", "")
```

> Explanation of above formula: The COUNTIF Function counts number of corresponding occurrences of Legal_id, in Sheet 2 Legal_id column. If count = 0 i.e means legal_id is not present in Sheet 2, so we use IF statement to assign 'N/A' value in Helper column else nothing ''.
> Same explanation follows for sheet 2.

Now We Filter the Rows with N/A values to delete as mentioned by you in comments. or Insert it in third Sheet by copy paste.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to accomplish your task is to use vba. But, if you want to use the `ISNA(MATCH` formula, you will need to wrap your formula in an `IF` statement and place the formula in each cell in `Sheet3`.

**STEP 1:** Paste the below formula in `Cell A2`

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(Sheet1!A2,Sheet2!A:A,0)),Sheet1!A2,"")
```

**STEP 2:** hold down `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` to enter it as an array formula

**STEP 3:** Hover over the dot in the right-bottom corner of the cell and drag down to the number of used rows you have in `Sheet1` ***Note:*** the formula will change for each row

**STEP 4:** Then drag across to `Column C` ***Note:*** the formula will change for each column

The data from `Sheet1` that is not in `Sheet2` will now be in `Sheet3`, separated by blank rows, you can select the blank rows and delete them.